# Rails 3 - Custom Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm somewhat confused by my options for custom validations in Rails 3, and i'm hoping that someone can point me in the direction of a resource that can help with my current issue.

I currently have 3 models, `vehicle`, `trim` and `model_year`. They look as follows:
`class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :make_id, :model_id, :trim_id, :model_year_id
  belongs_to :trim
  belongs_to :model_year
end`

class ModelYear < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value
  has_many :model_year_trims
  has_many :trims, :through => :model_year_trims
end

class Trim < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value, :model_id
  has_many :vehicles
  has_many :model_year_trims
  has_many :model_years, :through => :model_year_trims
end

My query is this - when I am creating a vehicle, how can I ensure that the model_year that is selected is valid for the trim (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

you can use custom validation method, as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods):

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :model_year_valid_for_trim

  def model_year_valid_for_trim
    if #some validation code for model year and trim
      errors.add(:model_years, "some error")
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 30):

You can use the `ActiveModel::Validator` class like so:

```
class VehicleValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    return true if # custom model_year and trip logic
    record.errors[:base] << # error message
  end
end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :make_id, :model_id, :trim_id, :model_year_id
  belongs_to :trim
  belongs_to :model_year

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with VehicleValidator
end
```

Comment: This is much cleaner in the long run. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Where should you put your custom validators?  What directory?

Comment: I keep mine in `lib/validators`. I've seen others put it in `app/validators`. It's up to you. Just make sure you add it to your load path in config.

Comment: Isn't the idea that app is for app specific code and lib is for code you intend to reuse in another project? So then lib/validators for reusable validators and app/validators for an application specific validator.

Comment: This is a great solution.